# UDP Socket not reading from server in Go

Tags: sockets, go, server, dns, udp

I'm developing a fast dns client in go just to mess around with But I'm facing troubles at the time of reading from server responses cause it never arrives and I know it actually did because I have WireShark open and it read the packet.

Here is the code sample(8.8.8.8 is Google DNS and the hex msg is a valid DNS query):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "encoding/hex"
    "bufio"
)

func CheckError(err error) {
    if err  != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: " , err)
    }
}

func main() {

    Conn, err := net.Dial("udp", "8.8.8.8:53")
    CheckError(err)

    defer Conn.Close()
    msg, _ := hex.DecodeString("5ab9010000010000000000001072312d2d2d736e2d68357137646e65650b676f6f676c65766964656f03636f6d0000010001")
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(Conn)
    buf := []byte(msg)
    _, err1 := Conn.Write(buf)
    if err1 != nil {
        fmt.Println(msg, err1)
    }
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Bytes())
    }
}
```

Here you have the proof that it actually arrives:
[WireShark Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRmQl.png)

I've testes reading directly from conn with:

```
func main() {

    Conn, err := net.Dial("udp", "8.8.8.8:53")
    CheckError(err)

    defer Conn.Close()
    msg, _ := hex.DecodeString("5ab9010000010000000000001072312d2d2d736e2d68357137646e65650b676f6f676c65766964656f03636f6d0000010001")
    buf := []byte(msg)
    _, err1 := Conn.Write(buf)
    if err1 != nil {
        fmt.Println(msg, err1)
    }
    Reader(Conn)
}

func Reader(conn net.Conn) {
    var buf []byte
    for {
        conn.Read(buf)
        fmt.Println(buf)
    }
}
```

Comment: Read directly from the connection, it doesn't make any sense to use buffered IO around a UDP connection.

Comment: @JimB Read does not work neither

Comment: Please show what you tried. Reading the datagram directly from `Conn` works fine.

Comment: @JimB I just posted how I was trying to do it

Comment: That's not how you use an `io.Reader`. You need space to read into, and you need to use the number bytes read value that's returned.

Comment: @JimB Oh I see, Thanks! It worked now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `bufio` around a UDP connection. UDP is not a stream oriented protocol, so you need to differentiate the individual datagrams yourself, and avoid partial reads to prevent data loss.

In order to read from an `io.Reader`, you must have space allocated to read into, and you need to use the bytes read value returned from the `Read` operation. Your example could be reduced to:

```
conn, err := net.Dial("udp", "8.8.8.8:53")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer conn.Close()

msg, _ := base64.RawStdEncoding.DecodeString("WrkBAAABAAAAAAAAEHIxLS0tc24taDVxN2RuZWULZ29vZ2xldmlkZW8DY29tAAABAAE")
resp := make([]byte, 512)

conn.Write(msg)

n, err := conn.Read(resp)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%q\n", resp[:n])
```